# how to build modules simulating a class library and controlling scope usage

Tags: javascript

I'm starting using OO concepts in Javascript.

So, I have several "class" js files simulating each one an OO object. 
Each class is defined in a single file, like myClass1.js, myClass2.js, etc.

Each class looks like:

```
// FILE myproject.classlib.myClass1

// "Class"
function myClass1(param1, param2){

   // Properties
   this.prop1 = param1;
   this.prop2 = param2;
}

/// "Methods"
myClass1.prototype.doSomething = function(){

    alert('myClass1 Hello world. prop1=' + this.prop1);
    alert('myClass1 Hello world. prop2=' + this.prop2);
}
```

Now I need to build a module to control usage scope of these classes and organize them into "libraries".

Something that would allow me to use something like:

```
var instance1 = new myProject.myClassLibrary1.myClass1('a', 'b');
var instance2 = new myProject.myClassLibrary1.myClass2('c', 'd');

var instance3 = new myProject.myClassLibrary2.myClass1('e', 'f');
var instance4 = new myProject.myClassLibrary2.myClass2('g', 'h');

instance1.doSomething(); /// prop1=a prop2=b
instance2.doSomething(); /// prop1=c prop2=d
instance3.doSomething(); /// prop1=e prop2=f
instance4.doSomething(); /// prop1=g prop2=h
```

How to I define my original class code definition so that it belongs to myClassLibraryN and to myProject ?

How can I make use of this library as the second code?

Comment: `var myProject = { myClassLibrary1: { myClass1: myClass1, ... } };` - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while [@Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901039/1592398) answer is correct, I'd like to tell you a bit better way on declaring namespaces without polluting the global namespace

```
var myProject = myProject || {};
myproject.myClassLibrary1 = {};

(function (namespace, undefined) {
    // private properties
    var foo = "foo",
        bar = "bar";

    // public methods and properties
    namespace.foobar = "foobar";
    namespace.myClass1 = function () {
        speak("hello world");
    };

    // private method
    function speak(msg) {
        console.log("You said: " + msg);
    };
})(myproject.myClassLibrary1);
```

Comment: Also, pascal casing classes are a common way to differentiate normal functions from functions intended to act like a class constructor. If someone thinks it's a normal function and doesn't prepend the 'new' keyword before a class constructor, "this" will refer to window. Very hard bug to find!

Answer (score 1):

You could create namespaces like so:

```
var namespace1 = namespace1 || {};
namespace1.namespace2 = namespace1.namespace2 || {};
namespace1.namespace2.MyClass = function() {
    //Constructor code...
    this.x = 0;
};
namespace1.namespace2.MyClass.prototype.increment = function() {
    this.x++;
};
// And so on...
```

The first line basically checks has namespace1 been defined yet and if so, doesn't create it; however, we create an empty object, so we can attach values onto the object otherwise.

Comment: @Mendez Where does this answer refer to anything but plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for strategies to organize code into libraries/namespaces. If it's so, just try to Google with key words "JavaScript namespace". The following is one blog found for you: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/. Hope it helps.